# Laravel How to use external variable on join

Tags: laravel, variables, join

I'm trying to pass two  external variables on my join query.

```
return DB::table('areas')->where("areas", $training_area_id)
            ->join('schools', function($join) use ($school_id){
                $school_id = auth()->user()->school_id;
                $join->on('schools.id', '=', $school_id);
            })
            ->join('locations', function($join){
                $join->on('locations.id', '=', 'areas');
                $join->on('locations.school_id', '=', 'schools.id');
            })
            ->get();
```

When i  use this  query.  It tries to use $school_id variable as "column" like  schools`.`id`=`1`.

How can I use that external variable on join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DB::raw()`

```
   ->join('schools', function($join){
        $school_id = auth()->user()->school_id;
        $join->on('schools.id', '=', DB::raw($school_id));
    })
```